# Pearson Correlation with multiple observations per each level of independent variable

Tags: correlation, repeated-measures, pearson-r

I am giving different doses of a drug to mice and measuring a quantitative response. I want to determine if there is a linear relationship between the dose of the drug and the response. Pearson correlation seems to be able to do that.

But I am testing multiple mice per each dose, so I have several observations of the dependent variable per each level of the independent variable. And I am interested in the correlation between the dose and the true population mean of the response in each dose. I would like to know the r and p values (in standard Pearson terminology), i.e. how strong the relationship is and how statistically significant it is.

So I need something like Pearson correlation on repeated measures, but I wasn't able to find any application of that (although I thought it is a pretty typical situation and common analysis). Could you please suggest how to do such an analysis?

Comment: Why did you say of repeated measures? I don't see it here. It sounds to me from your description that you a kind of give dose I to mice 1,2,3; dose II to mice 4,5,6, etc.

Comment: Yes, I had that design in mind. "Repeated measures" might be an incorrect description. I though that maybe we can think of it as "repeated measures" of the same dose, but I am not sure if that is valid.

At the same time, I would be also interested in how to analyze the true "repeated measures" design, in which each mouse receives each dose. If there is a solution to that, it would also work for me.